# No Internet access with DHCP Relay VLANs

Tags: networking, routing, dhcp, switch, vlan

I have a router that I can't manage (it is an ISP thing). It is directly connected to a T2600G-18TS (let's call it X) switch. The X switch has a static IP assigned from the routers IP range. I have another T2600G-18TS (let's call it Y) switch that is connected to a X switch. It also has a static IP assigned from the routers IP range. Next I would like to have 3 VLANs so I followed this tutorial about DHCP relay [click](https://www.tp-link.com/pl/support/faq/1630). The only change is 192.168.0.1 is the ISP's router IP and X's IP address is 192.168.0.9. Everything seems to be working, different ports assigned to specific VLANs get proper IPs etc. The only problem I have and can't resolve on my own is Internet access. When I connect directly to the X switch my computer gets IP address from the routers IP range and I can access the Internet. However, whichever VLAN I connect (using the Y switch) I get proper IP address (from VLAN), proper gateway, proper DNS (which I set up manually in the DHCP pool config) but when I try to ping whatever IP in the outside world (say 8.8.8.8) I immediately get 'Network unreachable'. Local connections are working. I feel that I miss some routing. So when I am connected to VLAN10 (according to the tutorial I linked) my gateway is 192.168.10.1 but I can't access the Internet. What route(s) am I missing?

I don't include any drawing or sachems as my network configuration is exactly the same as specified in the link.

Comment: Your ISP router doesn’t know how to route traffic to your other VLANs. Normally you would configure static routes on it, but you say you can’t manage it. That’s a problem.

Comment: Well, I used wrong words. I can't manage ISP's router directly but I can call helpdesk and they can do a change for me. What routing should they add in order to reach Internet from VLANs?

Answer (score 0):

The ISP router needs static routes for your other VLANs.  The next hop is your layer 3 switch.

Comment: So, ISP's router IP is 192.168.0.1 and if I understand correctly by 'layer 3 switch' you mean switch A which serves as a DHCP server for VLANs (192.168.0.9). I set up a static route on router with destination 192.168.10.0 and next hop 192.168.0.9. When I connect to the proper port on switch B (VLAN with 192.168.10.x) I am still getting 'Network unreachable'.

Comment: can you ping 192.168.0.9 from vlan 10?

Comment: Yes, I can ping 192.168.0.9 being connected to VLAN10 but I can't ping 192.168.0.1.

Comment: Does switch a have a default route?

Comment: Yes, switches A and B have default routes set (static ones) - dest. 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0 
next hop 192.168.0.1. Switches can ping outside world (I checked that using internal maintenance tool) and use NTP to synchronize their time.

Comment: Ok. I need to see your switch configurations. Please edit your question to include them.

Comment: I solved the issue myself. I bought a router to mimic the configuration I can't manage (the real router is managed by my ISP) and test the whole thing instead of calling helpdesk all the time. I connected my router to the switch A and used ISP's router as WAN. It turned out that everything was Ok. Guys at helpdesk set wrong routes which caused packets to be lost. After I called them and corrected the values they set everything is working like a charm.